# How to skip an element in foreach when debugging with visual studio?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008

I have this piece of code

```
foreach(Datarow row in dt.Rows)
{
    //here goes the stuff
}
```

Now what I want to do, is skip a particular element in the foreach.

I tried to call

```
dt.Rows.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
```

via the `Quick Watch` window
But it seemed to give no result. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can give the if() condition

Comment: yeah, but i don't want to touch the code, i'm interested in the direct way, using the QuickWatch or some other debug tool

Comment: Drag the yellow arrow to the end of the loop?

Comment: Debug into it on that iteration and type continue into the Immediate Window?

Comment: @Nanhydrin - That doesn't work.  You just get "Invalid expression term".

Answer (score 2):

Either right-click the end of the loop and select 'Set Next Statement', or drag the yellow arrow to the end of the loop.

Comment: yeah i tried that, but it doesn't stand on that line, when i try to move the current debuggable line to the end of the loop body, it catches the other line, right after the loop

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there.  Do you mean it's executing the last line of the loop?  If so, set the next statement as the final brace "}".

Comment: I mean i can't set it as the "}" :) it just doesn't go there)

Comment: Is there a mismatch between the source and the executing code?

Comment: No, there isn't. It just doesn't stop on the final brace so i could go to the next element

Comment: What doesn't stop on the final brace?

Comment: I don't know, i drag the arrow to the brace, and it doesn't want to catch it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76535/discussion-between-ian-and-carmine).

Comment: dragging the arrow outside the for loop resulted in strange runtime results